# Make hook_menu() argument as global variable

Tags: 7, ajax, routes

here's the code from my module:

```
function vasya_init() {
  // ajax framework
  drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
  drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery.form');
}

function vasya_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['get_alt/%/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'alt_getter',
    'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function alt_getter($get_alt = NULL, $mode = NULL) {
  if ($mode != 'ajax') {
    drupal_set_message('Turn Javascript');
    drupal_goto(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '<front>');
  }

  // globals
  $GLOBALS['get_alt'] = $get_alt;

  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_html('.big-image', $GLOBALS['test']);
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}

function vasya_node_view($node, $view_mode) {
      $test = theme(
  'image_style', array('style_name' => 'node-image', 'path' => $field_sell->field_photo['und'][$GLOBALS['get_alt']]['uri'], 'alt' => $GLOBALS['get_alt'])
);
}
```

On the node page i have a links:

```
<a href="/get_alt/0/nojs" class="use-ajax">
<img width="80" height="80" alt="0" src="myhiddenpath" typeof="foaf:Image">
</a>

<a href="/get_alt/1/nojs" class="use-ajax">
<img width="80" height="80" alt="1" src="myhiddenpath" typeof="foaf:Image">
</a>

<a href="/get_alt/2/nojs" class="use-ajax">
<img width="80" height="80" alt="2" src="myhiddenpath" typeof="foaf:Image">
</a>
```

When i click on one of these links it gets an argument i.e. 1, 2 or 3. This argument is stored in a variable `$get_alt`. Then i want to send the value of $get_alt to a function `vasya_node_view()` through `$GLOBALS`.

But it shows undefined index 'get_alt' message. Can someone help me?

Comment: If alt_getter() is the callback function, when is vasya_node_view() called in the same HTTP petition?

Comment: callback function, in my case alt_getter() is firing when i click on one of the links above on the node page (e.g. /node/10)

Comment: So, node hook_node_view is fired *before* alt_getter(), when page is rendered. After that, you click on a link that fires alt_getter().

Comment: Exactly :) Do you have any ideas, why it's not working?

Comment: Because when you try to read the value in the vasya_node_view()the value is not yet set because is going to be set when alt_getter() is executed, in the next HTTP petition.

Comment: @Heihachi Globals only exist per single-page-request - you're looking for a [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)